# Internet Explorer 8 choking on function call (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have this line in a function handling click events. It works in Firefox, but not IE8 and I don't see how to create a workaround. (Jquery answers welcome!).

n.b I cannot use the this keyword as in context it will be useless.

```
elementsList[i].previousSibling.lastChild.addEventListener("click", (function(el){
            return function(){
                 toggle(el)
             };
       })(elementsList[i]),false);
```

edit

To answer comments

elementsList is an array containing various nodes such as divs and p tags.

Comment: FWIW, in IE8 and below, the equivalent is `attachEvent`. Have a look at http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: If you show us what elementsList is we can provide jQuery code

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer does not support addEventListener [before version 9](http://www.davidflanagan.com/2010/03/ie9-will-have-a.html).

Use a library to iron out the differences, since you mentioned jQuery, use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$( elementsList[i] ).prev().last().click(function() {
    toggle( this );
});
```

Comment: Jquery handles the this keyword differently than standard Javascript? Also beginning to seriously like Jquery

Comment: @YsoL8: No it does not. `this` will refer to the DOM element the event handler is bound to.